# Multiple extremely short lived session attributes in an application

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a jsp page that displays all records from the database. There is a delete button under each column. The code of the servlet that deletes a record is.

```
new userDao().get(User.Class,Long.parseLong("id")).delete();
// for some reasons I cannot use requestDispatcher, so I store the delete successful message in a session
request.getSession().setAttribute("message","Delete successful.");
// view.html is a servlet that gets all records
response.sendRedirect("view.html");
```

And in the view.html servlet

```
request.setAttribute("message",get the message attribute from HTTPSession);
request.getSession().removeAttribute("message");
// go back to jsp
request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Many of my pages are like this. I understand sessions are used for data that spans multiple requests, but is what I'm doing fine or bad practice? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("view.html?message=" + URLEncoder.encodeURL("D...", "UTF-8"));` maybe? With either a view.jsp (session=false, ${para.message}) or JavaScript

Comment: @JoopEggen if you use this approach, be very careful about code injection attacks.

Comment: Frameworks call these "flash attributes", and try avoiding multi-tab concurrency issues that they cause: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-flash-attributes

Comment: @JiriTousek the delete activity already happened, view is just the result. But yes, the first code line buggered me too.

Comment: @JoopEggen That's not what I meant - what I meant is that if you take a message from URL parameter and display it, you need to escape it so that noone can use it to insert their code into your page this way (aka. XSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the frameworks do it, too. There's basically not many other places that could be used to store these messages across page redirects. So most frameworks just use some sort of state (view state, flow state, or whatever the framework calls it), then store this whole object on session.

Also not that you're *not*, according to your example, using any *short-lived* sessions - it could well be that you're using one long-lasting session, and only its content is short-lived. Lastly, what you're setting on session isn't propagated to client (client only holds the session ID) and most often it will be probably held in memory, so frequent changes in session's data shouldn't be a problem.